# virtualenv not working on windows cygwin

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have cygwin installed on a windows 7 machine. I'm trying to follow the instructions listed here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_environment.htm

1. Created a new project directory
2. cd into the new directory
3. Typed virtualenv venv, and it created the new virtual dir successfully
4. This next step fails to work for me.

I'm trying to activate the virtual env but its not working.

"venv\scripts\activate"

When i type that nothing happens.

USER@PCTEST~/newproj
$ venv/Scripts/activate

USER@PCTEST ~/newproj
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/python27/python

Comment: Have you tried `source venv\scripts\activate` ?

Comment: thanks metmirr. I have yep, this is what happens:

USER@PCTEST~/newproj
$ source venv/scripts/activate

(venv)
USER@PCTEST ~/newproj

$ which python
/home/USER/newproj/venv/Scripts/python
(venv)

USER@PCTEST ~/newproj
$ python

In other words, it seems to have activated, but then when i type "python" the interpreter doesn't seem to be working, it just stalls there.

Comment: Haha really ? But what about the python command then not working in the environment ? How can i activate the python interpreter in that new virtual environment ?

Comment: Close this cmd window, open new one and try same.

Comment: Yep tried in new window, same behavior :|

Comment: Seems like your env is activated propperly. Python might be "not working" because of Cygwin output buffering. Try running python with `python -i` to start in interactive mode and force it print output.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

Run activate script with `source` or `.` (dot space) command:

```
source ./venv/Scripts/activate

# Or

. ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

**Explanation**

`source` runs shell commands in your current shell environment, so venv works as expected. While running script by name starts new isolated shell environment, activates venv there and closes new shell environment returning to original one.